# How to automatically load a google apps script menu on all user accounts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-account

I've searched around for this, but haven't found any info.  I've written a few scripts that are bound to certain google docs/sheets.  Instead of being bound to a particular doc/sheet, is it possible to have a google action script that loads whenever anyone in my google user account group opens a new or existing doc/sheet?

I know how to [load a menu UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene).  That's simple.  I know how to [create a stand-alone script](https://script.google.com/home/start).  I'm asking for something different.  Basically, I want to create a deployment suite of proprietary scripts for our company, and whenever a current or future user of our group opens any new or current Google docs/sheets, the menu appears in their UI.

Is this possible, or do I have to ask my users to "install" my suite every time?

If this exists in GAS, I don't know where to look.

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to have something like an internal add-on that runs automatically on every Google Sheet and gets automatically install for all the users so it is available for everyone within your organization with every single file they create, correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to do.  Should I be developing this as an "add-on?"  If yes, how is it different, and how can I ensure all my user-group accounts have this automatically on their sessions of Google Docs and Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you want to have the script available as a "button" that can be accessible by any user from any Sheet or Doc I think the only way to do this is by deploying your script as an add-on then make it available internally through the Google Workspace Marketplace and do a domain installation of this add-on so it gets installed for all your users automatically.

First you would need to create the script and deploy it as an add-on. You can skip the part of the OAuth verification process because you are not publishing a public add-on but just an internal add-on for your organization.

After that make sure to add the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK to your Google Cloud Platform project. In the App configuration section from the Marketplace SDK set everything as internal/private and mark the Google services where you want it to be available and create the store listing.

Once you finish that you will see the app has been approved and an installation link. Make sure to install it domain wide and wait a couple of minutes for it to appear in all your files (from the selected Google services during the configuration) for all your users.

The result should look something like this:

[image]

#### References:

- [Create and manage deployments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments)
- [Publish an app](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish)